# Polynomial Functions Problem

Tags: polynomials

If $f(x)=x^2+1$ and $g(x)=x-1$, for all real numbers $x$, for what real number $a$ does  $f(g(-a))= g(f(-a))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $f(x)=x^2+1$ and $g(x)=x-1$

$$f(g(-a))=g(f(-a))$$
$$f(-a-1)=g(a^2+1)$$
$$a^2+2+2a=a^2+1-1$$
$$a=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$f(g(-x)) = (-(x-1))^2+1$$
so, expand it. Do the same for $g(f(-x))$.

Thus, you get a equality of the form
$$ax^2+bx+c=px^2+qx+r.$$

Just solve it.